# Distributed Caching in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to enable caching between pods in Kubernetes cluster? For eg: Lets say we have more than 1 pods running on High availability mode.And we want to share some value between them using distributed caching between the pods.Is this something possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are some experimental projects to let you reuse the etcd that powers the cluster, but I probably wouldn’t. Just run your own using etcd-operator or something. The specifics will massively depend on what your exact use case and software is, distributed databases are among the most complex things ever.